# Python write to csv file from Dict

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, jupyter-notebook, character-encoding

[See excel file SS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QfXMN.png) [The data looks as in image in csv file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F7ov6.png)

1. This is what I have written till now to analyze reviews from IMDB.
   First it fetches the reviews from imdb website (top 250 movies).
2. Then fetches the movie links, reviews links, extracts text from the reviews and stores it in a dictionary data format with movie_name: movie review format.
3. In the last step, I am able to print the Movie_Name: Movie review on the console. But when I write to CSV file it gives either errors or writes just incorrect data to CSV file.

```
import urllib.request, urllib.parse, urllib.error
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import ssl
import csv
import requests
import re
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
nltk.download('stopwords')
nltk.download('punkt')
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize

# Ignore SSL certificate errors
ctx = ssl.create_default_context()
ctx.check_hostname = False
ctx.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.77 Safari/537.36'}


url = input('Enter - ')
while (True):
    try:
        page = requests.get(url, headers = headers)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")
        container = soup.find_all('td', class_ = 'titleColumn')
        break
    except:
        print("Please enter a valid url:")
        url = input('Enter - ')

def movies_list():
    movie_names = []
    movies = container[:100] #here we get the top 50 movies we want
    for movie in movies:
        name = movie.find('a').text
        movie_names.append(name)
    return movie_names
#print(movie_names)


def movie_links_list():
    movie_links = []
    movies = container[:100]
    for movie in movies:
        tag = movie.find('a')`enter code here`
        link = tag.get('href', None)
        movie_links.append(link)
    for i in range(len(movie_links)):
            movie_links[i] = 'https://www.imdb.com/'+ movie_links[i]
    return movie_links

def review_link_list(movie_links):
    review_links = []
    for movie_link in movie_links:
        title_pos = movie_link.find('title')
        nxt_slash = movie_link.find('/', title_pos)
        nxt2_slash = movie_link.find('/', nxt_slash+1)
        review_link = movie_link[:title_pos-1] + movie_link[title_pos:nxt2_slash+1] + "reviews?ref_=tt_urv"
        review_links.append(review_link)
    return review_links


def get_reviews(review_links):
    movie_names=movies_list()
    review_dict={}
    for i in range(len(review_links)):
        movie_name=movie_names[i]
        movie_reviews=[]
        review_page = requests.get(review_links[i], headers = headers)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(review_page.content, "html.parser")
        tag = soup.find_all('div', class_ = 'content') #find_all to return a list
        top_50= tag[:50]
        for j in top_50:
            try:
                review=j.select('div.show-more__control')[0].text
            except:
                continue
            movie_reviews.append(review)
        review_dict[movie_name]=movie_reviews
    return review_dict

file= "abc.csv"
with open(file ,'w') as csvfile:
    for i in range(len(movies)):
        csvwriter = csv.writer(csvfile)
        Name=movies[i]
        Review = reviews_dict[Name]
        try:
            csvwriter.writerow(Review)
        except:
            csvwriter.writerow("Review does not exist")
```

Comment: What is the error you received? For now, try to edit this part `csv.writer(csvfile)` to `csv.writer(csvfile,delimiter=',')` and see if it does the trick.

Comment: In that acse it gives TypeError: 'delimeter' is an invalid keyword argument for this function

Answer (score 0):

you need to open the file and write a list with the data

```py
import csv
dict = {"mykey":10}

with open("mydata.csv", 'a') as file:
   writer = csv.writer(file)
   for key, value in dict.items():
     data = [key, value]
     writer.writerow(data)
```

in the csv file "mydata.csv" you will no get

```
mykey,10
```

When using the 'a' as an args in open you can append data to the file so not to over write old data

Comment: This Method works with couple of enteries. But in my data len(dict) is 100, dict.key = movie_name and dict value is a list of 25 reviews about that movie. so, total 100 lists with around 1 million words. Writing this data causes data loss and unnecessary newlines